# CSS `vertical-align: middle` doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

I would expect that the following html document results in a red square vertically centered within a yellow square:

```
<html>
<body>

<div style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:yellow">

    <div style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;vertical-align:middle">

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But it results in one that is aligned to the top of its parent div.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Q4hj/)

What am I doing wrong?  Why isn't `vertical-align:middle` working?

Answer (score 2):

The vertical-align property affects the vertical positioning inside a line box of the boxes generated by an inline-level element. [Here are more details!](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align)

Comment: Beat me to the fiddle... anyway, just check the reference if you have any questions. W3C usually answers most CSS questions!

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="display: table-cell; width:200px;height:200px;background-color:yellow; vertical-align:middle">
    <div style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;">
    </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/322me/)